# Python: Taking parameter input and returning output equation

Tags: python, function

I am working on a project that requires a function (I'll call it target) that will take an input named parameter_vector and will output an equation for other functions to take as an input. The output equation I am using as a test case is the standard quadratic equation:

```
Ax^2 + Bx + C
```

My target function will take a parameter_vector in that looks like:

```
parameter_vector = [A, B, C]
```

and will use these indices as coefficients in writing out my equation as an output. Here is my code so far:

```
def target(parameter_vector):
    pv = parameter_vector
    x = pv[0]*x**2 + pv[1]*x + pv[2]
    return x
```

As I'm sure you can guess, the following error pops up in my shell:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment
```

So I did a little research and came across the lambda variable that is used for place-holding a variable. I tried to input:

```
x = pv[0]*lambda**2 + pv[1]*x +pv[2]
```

But this popped up:

```
File "source_parameters.py", line 7
x = pv[0]*lambda**2 + pv[1]*lambda +pv[2]
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Am I approaching this completely wrong? I'm sure even sure whether the output should be a string or not. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misunderstood how lambdas work; they create a function from an expression. Given `x` as input, that'd look like this:

```
lambda x: pv[0]*x**2 + pv[1]*x + pv[2]
```

The expression produces a function object, which you can return directly from your `target()` function:

```
def target(pv):
    return lambda x: pv[0]*x**2 + pv[1]*x + pv[2]
```

You could unpack the `parameter_vector` into the three components first to make it clearer you need to have 3 values in it:

```
def target(parameter_vector):
    a, b, c = parameter_vector
    return lambda x: a * x ** 2 + b * x + c
```

or you can generalise this to any length of `parameter_vector`:

```
def target(parameter_vector):
    return lambda x: sum(p * x ** (len(parameter_vector) - i - 1)
                         for i, p in enumerate(parameter_vector))
```

Quick demo:

```
>>> lambda x: pv[0]*x**2 + pv[1]*x + pv[2]
<function <lambda> at 0x102a0c6e0>
>>> def target(parameter_vector):
...     a, b, c = parameter_vector
...     return lambda x: a * x ** 2 + b * x + c
... 
>>> new_function = target([3, 2, 5]) # 3x^2 + 2x + 5
>>> new_function
<function <lambda> at 0x102a0c7d0>
>>> new_function(2)
21
>>> new_function(3)
38
>>> new_function(4)
61
>>> def target(parameter_vector):
...     return lambda x: sum(p * x ** (len(parameter_vector) - i - 1)
...                          for i, p in enumerate(parameter_vector))
... 
>>> new_function = target([3, 2, 5])
>>> new_function(2)
21
>>> new_function = target([3, 2, 5, -2])  # 3x^3 + 2x^2 + 5x - 2
>>> new_function(2)
40
```

Comment: Great! That is exactly what I am looking for. Is there a way to define an unknown number of indices in place of a,b,c for a more complex function? Let's say it has 12 coefficients but isn't known to the function prior to importing a different script. Is there a way to generalize each index but still use the unpacking step?

Comment: @ibanez221: no, unpacking won't let you do that. You'd have to use a `sum()` of the parameters, each multiplied with `x` to the power `len(parameter_vector) - index` (where `index` is the index of the current parameter): `lambda x: sum(p * x ** (len(pv) - i - 1) for i, p in enumerate(pv))`.

Comment: @ibanez221: added that option to the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much! I never would have come up with that solution. This is very helpful, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right track. You can return a `lambda` function as follows.

```
def target(pv):
    return lambda i : pv[0]*i*i + pv[1]*i + pv[2]
```

Testing that we do get a function back

```
>>> target([1,3,4])
<function target.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x029E8DB0>
```

Let's assign the function to `f`

```
>>> f = target([1,3,4])
```

Now we can call the function with an argument

```
>>> f(5)
44
```